# Can I memory map a file and still allow other processes to write to it?

Tags: windows, winapi, memory, file-io

I am using the following code to memory-map a file for reading in windows (Windows 10):

```
HANDLE windowsFileHdl = CreateFileA(filePath, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
if (windowsFileHdl == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
  return false;
}

HANDLE fileMappedHdl = CreateFileMappingA(windowsFileHdl, 0, PAGE_READONLY, 0, 0, nullptr);
char* baseFileData = (char*)MapViewOfFile(fileMapedHdl, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0);
```

I would still like others to write to this file while I am reading it. Is this possible?

Currently, I get an error like this:

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

The above error was received by trying to open the file in a separate program (Notepad) while I had it memory mapped.

Is this a limitation with how the OS maps the file to memory or am I missing some flag?

EDIT:
@zett42 pointed out that I am missing FILE_SHARE_READ adding this makes the code:

```
HANDLE windowsFileHdl = CreateFileA(filePath, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
if (windowsFileHdl == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
  return false;
}

HANDLE fileMappedHdl = CreateFileMappingA(windowsFileHdl, 0, PAGE_READONLY, 0, 0, nullptr);
char* baseFileData = (char*)MapViewOfFile(fileMapedHdl, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0);
```

Now, notepad is able to open and write to the file!

However other programs like Visual Studio, Notepad++, or Emacs still have errors when writing to the file.

Visual Studio error:

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Notepad++ error:

> The file cannot be saved and it may be protected. Do you want to launch Notepad++ in Administrator mode?

Comment: Even if you can, how do you plan on ensuring writes from other processes are both complete and fully visible in the process that has the file mapped?

Comment: You are missing `FILE_SHARE_READ`.

Comment: @zett42 Thanks! Yeah forgot that. I am now able to open it and edit with notepad. However, with other programs like notepad++ I get an error saying that the file might still be protected.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, that is a good question. Ideally, I would like some notification if the file has been written to. However, for this program whether the writes are completed is not a factor, I am just trying to prevent the memory mapping from affecting other functionality of other programs

Comment: @zett42 to clarify, I get the error in notepad++ and other programs like emacs or visual studio when attempting to write. Visual Studio says: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Comment: That's because those programs want to open the file exclusively. So you can't achieve what you want.

Comment: Now, notification that the file has been written to won't help you. What you need is synchronisation. All parties need to synchronise. It's pretty clear that what you are trying to do is not going to solve your problem, whatever it actually is.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, thank you for the clarification. Essentially, I am just trying to read and parse text data. I was using the normal ReadFile calls but noticed that they were taking a significant amount of time. I switched to memory-mapped file io and speed increased drastically but ran into some issues as mentioned in the post.

Comment: I guess my options are to go back to ReadFile or to reduce the time that files are mapped to memory to decrease the chance for contention.

Comment: Memory mapped files aren't what you need. Just pass a decent sized buffer to ReadFile. In any case, your problems with sharing are the same whether you read the file by ReadFile or by memory mapping. If you want to read a file, how can you expect to allow some other process to write to that part of the file at the same time?

Comment: Now, talking about reducing the chance of contention is all wrong. You can't program based on chance!! Make sure that your program works all the time.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan so there is still a chance of contention even with using ReadFile? Is this because the OS still needs to copy the file contents to the provided buffer and any attempts to write to the file during this copy then will fail?

Comment: Well, if two entities are reading and writing at the same time, without synchronisation, then the outcome is I'll defined. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Contention isn't the problem you need to solve. We have contention all the time. But you cannot let the contention continue to run into concurrent, unsynchronized access. That's the issue you need to solve. [LockFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-lockfile) can be a solution.